# What parameter should I pass when it is "self"

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on an auto-scaler for the images in my program and to test I am trying to scale a background image from 800 x 600 to 1366 x 720 and I have written the following code;

```
class ImageTransformer():
    def __init__(self):

        self.displayHeight = Display.displayHeight
        self.displayWidth = Display.displayWidth

    def imageScaler(self):
        if self.displayWidth == 1366 & self.displayHeight == 720:
            ResourceLoader.bg = pygame.transform.scale(ResourceLoader.bg,                   (1366, 766))
```

and am trying to call it by using;

```
def renderGameImages(self):
    ImageTransformer.imageScaler()
```

however I am stuck on the parameter I should give it, can you guys help?

Comment: Presumably the name `imageTransformer` used here (lowercase initial `i`) is a typo? You use `ImageTransformer` (uppercase initial `I`) elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thankyou for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't pass any parameter; the `self` parameter is taken care of for you, provided you use an *instance*:

```
ImageTransformer().imageScaler()
```

Here I create an instance of the `ImageTransformer()` class first, before calling a method on that instance.

You can create that instance separately, and store it somewhere first, then use that one instance to call the method on.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, creating a class doesn't seem necessary:

```
def imageScaler(self):
    if Display.displayWidth == 1366 & Display.displayHeight == 720:
        ResourceLoader.bg = pygame.transform.scale(ResourceLoader.bg, (1366, 766))
```

If you have lots of image transformations to implement, you can make a module.

Comment: The plan is to transform each of my assets to the monitors resolution :)